# Has anyone ever got more than a 21 Gun Salute?

Tags: united-states, military, world

The 21 gun salute is given at the funeral for US military personnel. Has there ever been someone who got more than 21 rounds fired?
Primarily for the US but not limited to I am looking for instances where someone got more than the 21 solute? I would like a 21001 50 cal gun solute, but for the price I might have to settle for bb guns.

Comment: Are you talking purely about the US (the tags say US and World)? For funerals only (which is usually called a [three-volley salute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-volley_salute))? Wikipedia has a [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/21-gun_salute) that lists the various circumstances for salutes.

Comment: Is this a question about the US gun salute only? Mark that clearly in your answer. Other nations have higher number of gun salutes.

Comment: Please specify where. In UK *"In (Royal Parks) an extra 20 rounds are added... At the Tower of London 62 rounds are fired on royal anniversaries (the basic 21, plus a further 20 because the Tower is a Royal Palace and Fortress, plus another 21 'for the City of London') and 41 on other occasions. The Tower of London probably holds the record for the most rounds fired in a single salute — 124 are fired whenever the Duke of Edinburgh's birthday (62 rounds) coincides with the Queen's official birthday ( 62 rounds)."* [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/21-gun_salute)

Comment: @TheHonRose thats an answer

Comment: James Richard Dacres, only they were fully loaded and fired at his ship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They weren't fired for an individual, but according to George Lensen's The Russian Push Toward Japan (pp. 148) the Dutch in Japan made salutes of 150 guns:

> ... the Dutch ships expected to leave their anchorage and, as was their custom, would salute the imperial fortress.... When the Dutch vessels duly departed from Deshima the following day, they saluted with a hundred and fifty guns each.... The Japanese did not return the salute.

Answer (score 11):

You really should read through the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/21-gun_salute) that [Steve Bird](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/6489/steve-bird) left in his comment.  This contains a lot of information from which I quote a couple of notable examples.

Back in the days of the Raj, Emperors used to earn a 101 gun salute.

In modern times, HRH Prince Philip earns 62 rounds on his Birthday and HM Queen Elizabeth II also earns 62 on her official birthday.  When the two dates are in coincidence, the two are combined into a single 124 gun salute.

Comment: `In modern times, HRH Prince Philip earns 62 rounds on his Birthday and HRH Queen Elizabeth II also earns 62 on her official birthday. When the two dates are in coincidence`. So at least one of their birthdays can change (in order for them to coincide)? :-P

Comment: Yes. The Queen has two birthdays her real one and an official one. Her official birthday is usually the second Saturday in June. Prince Philips birthday is the 10th June, so there’s sometimes the case that both fall on the same date.

Comment: @Snow Queen Elizabeth is HM, not HRH ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The British royal family will sometimes get [salutes](https://www.royal.uk/gun-salutes) of 41 guns or 62 guns. These are in increments of 21- 20- and 21- guns.